# Proving $\ln(1+x) < x$ for $x>0$ without the use of derivatives or the fact that a function is analytic.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

Earlier today I tried answering a question regarding the following identity (I'm using $\ln(x)$ to denote the natural logarithm):

$$\ln(1+x) < x, \text{ } \forall x > 0$$

The question (which was deleted before I could answer it) asked for a proof of this inequality without the help of the monotony of any of these two functions. I came up with the following proof:

$$\ln(1+x) < x$$

$$1+x < e^{x}$$

We know that the exponential is an analytcal function on the complex plane ([Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460377/is-exponential-function-analytic-over-all-complex-numbers)) and therefore the inequality can be written as:

$$1 + x < \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

$$1 + x < 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \dots$$

Since we know $x\neq 0 $ we can cancel it and are left with:

$$0 < \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \dots = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} := \Sigma_2(x)$$

Furthermore $x > 0$ implies: $x^n > 0, \text{ } \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x > 0$.

$$\Rightarrow \Sigma_2(x) > 0, \text{ } \forall x>0$$

$$\tag*{$\Box$}$$

---

My question now is if I instead could have used something more "elemantary", for example not using the series representation. So I'm essentially asking for an "easier" proof, which could be understood by someone who just learned about exponentials and their inverses.

Thanks in advance! :)

---

**Note:** The series representation can be used to define the exponential and an integral to define the logarithm, but I don't want to use these facts in my proof.

Comment: What are you taking as the definition of $e^x$ if not the series expansion?

Comment: What is your definition of $\ln x$?  Often one defines it as $\int \frac 1x dx$ so you have to use an integral.  Often one defines $e^x$ as the power series, so you have to use that.

Comment: Hard to define $e$ without using a limit, right?

Comment: Of course I have to have a limit for defining $e$ - forgot about that. But couldn't you just define the logarithm as the function $f(x)$ which fulfills the identity $e^{f(x)} = Id$?

Either way, i adjusted my question to your comments...

Comment: You can define the log that way if you define the exponential some other way.  Once you say the exponential function is analytic you have used much heavier machinery than monotony or limits or real derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the graph of $~f(t) = \dfrac{1}{1+t},~$ in the range $~0 \leq t \leq x.$

The area under the curve is

$$\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t}~dt = \log(1+x).$$

This is clearly less than the area of the rectangle whose $4$ corners are $~(0,0), ~(0,1), ~(x,0), ~(x,1).$

The reason for the inequality is that when $~t = 0,~$ $f(t) = \dfrac{1}{1+t} = 1,~$ and $~f(t)~$ is clearly a strictly decreasing function.

The area of the rectangle is $1 \times x = x.$

**Note**:
Consider this excerpt from the posting:

> ...without the help of the monotony of any of these two functions.

A case can be made that my proof is *out-of-bounds*, because I did use the fact that $f(t)$ is strictly decreasing.